# Query execution Error via PySpark - GC Error

Tags: pyspark, garbage-collection, impala

I have requirement to to extract row counts of each table in hive database(which has multiple schemas). I wrote pyspark job which extracts counts of each table, it works fine when i try for some of the schemas, however it fails with GV overhead error when i try for all schemas. i tried creating union all for all table queries across the database, also tried union all for all tables within schema. both have failed with the GC Error.

Can you please advise to avoid this error. below is my script:

```
    # For loop for Schema starts here
for schema in schemas_list:

# Dataframe with all table names available in given Schema for level1 and level2
    tables_1_df=tables_df(schema,1)
    tables_1_list=formatted_list(tables_1_df,1)
    tables_2_df=tables_df(schema,2)
    tables_2_list=formatted_list(tables_2_df,2)
    tables_list=list(set(tables_1_list) & set(tables_2_list)) #Intersection of level1 and level2 tables per Schema Name

# For loop for Tables starts her
    for table in tables_list:

    # Creating Dataframe with Row Count of given table for level 1 and level2
        level_1_query=prep_query(schema, table, 1)
        level_2_query=prep_query(schema, table, 2)
        level_1_count_df=level_1_count_df.union(table_count(level_1_query))
        level_1_count_df.persist()
        level_2_count_df=level_2_count_df.union(table_count(level_2_query))
        level_2_count_df.persist()

# Validate if level1 and level2 are re-conciled, if not write the row into data frame which will intern write into file in S3 Location
level_1_2_join_df = level_1_count_df.alias("one").join(level_2_count_df.alias("two"),(level_1_count_df.schema_name==level_2_count_df.schema_name) & (level_1_count_df.table_name==level_2_count_df.table_name),'inner').select(col("one.schema_name"),col("two.table_name"),col("level_1_count"),col("level_2_count"))
main_df=header_df.union(level_1_2_join_df)
if extracttype=='DELTA':
    main_df=main_df.filter(main_df.level_1_count!=main_df.level_2_count)
main_df=main_df.select(concat(col("schema_name"),lit(","),col("table_name"),lit(","),col("level_1_count"),lit(","),col("level_2_count")))

    # creates file in temp location
file_output(main_df, tempfolder) # writes to txt file in hadoop
```

Comment: could you run .explain() on your main_df maybe and post the logical and physical plan of how spark executes? it could be persist(heap memory maybe overloaded).. i think the join after persist creates Gc overhead.

Comment: i see, you are persisting every iteration of the union, so instead of persisting one big dataframe of  level_1_count/level_2_count, you are persisting each and every iteration(which is exponentially increasing in size) and it creates many unnecessary temporary objects in the heap which altogether weigh more than one final dataframe. try persisting final level_1_count/level_2_count outside the for loop.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad,

I did ran the same script without persisting any dataframe, i got the GC overhead error. So i thought query is becoming huge with union all's and failing with this error. Then i tried persisting the for every table then joining the level1 and level2 dataframes. This is failing while executing the query not at the joining dataframes.